# Best way to check for duplicates when adding a new Row in DataSets?

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

What is the most effective way to add new items to my DataSet, and making sure that if it's an duplicate item, that I update it instead of creating a new entry?

If I was writing this in mySQL I would use the 'On Duplicate' syntax.

Comment: How do you decide if a new item is duplicate of an existing item? By just looking at column with primary key, or some columns that you decide?

Comment: I'm using the column with primary key to determine if it's an duplicate item. I solved this temporarily by catching any error generated and if it's a duplicate using a LINQ query to update the existing item. I'm pretty sure this is bad practice or at least not very efficient. :)

Comment: I don't think it is a bad practice :) If you try to add a new item with an existing primary key, DataTable throws System.Data.ConstraintException, and you can handle it with catch block by updating the item of the table. Thats the way it is I think :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DataSet.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.merge.aspx) method. It has overloads that allow you to specify how the merge should performed, preserve or ignore changes, and how to treat new columns.

Also, if you want the merge to be effective, ensure that you have a primary key on all tables, because the DataSet builds an index over all the rows using the primary key. (Internally it's an RBTree)

Comment: Thanks, Pop Catalin. I think this may have been what I was looking for.